# How to add the new line in textarea using javascript

Tags: html, textarea, newline

I have the textarea "write_t". I use following code to change the value of textarea. The problem is '
' does not help me to add the new line. What do I wrong?

```
var el =document.forms[0].write_t;
el.value=el.value+'&#13;&#10;'+k+" some text";
```

Answer (score 2):

Use \n to add a new line.

```
var el =document.forms[0].write_t;
el.value=el.value+'&#13;&#10;'+k+"\nsome text";
```